# A generalization of unsolvable equation $ab-ba=1$ in a Banach algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras

It is well known that the  equation $$(*)\;\;\;\;ab-ba=1$$ is  unsolvable  in a Banach algebra.

I search for  some  reasonable  generalization of this equation in higher variable for  investigation of  solvability of such generalized equations. The above equation can be read as $$(**)\;\;\;\;\;\sum_{\sigma \in S_2} s(\sigma)\prod a_{\sigma_i}=1$$ provided we put $a_1=a,\;a_2=b.$

So our first question is the following:

> Is there a  Banach algebra  with three elements $a,b,c$  which satisfy the following equation?$$(***)\;\;\;\;\;abc+bca+cab-bac-cba-acb=1$$

Our next  question:

> Apart from $(***)$, What  would  be  some other   generalization of $(*)$ whose solvability in a  Banach algebra would  be  an interesting and  non trivial question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the algebra of real $2\times 2$ matrices, take
  $$ a=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{array} \right],\ 
     b=\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right],\ 
     c=\left[ \begin{array}{rr} 1/3 & 0\\ 0 & -1/3\end{array}\right]. $$
In the other direction, is it true that if for all $n$ an equation has no solutions in $n\times n$ real matrices, then it has no solutions in any Banach algebra? What are the equations (or finite sets of equations) that for all $n$ have no solutions in $n\times n$ real matrix algebras?

Comment: If you start out with a non-trivial finitely presented group $G$ that has no finite-dimensional representations, then you get relations that are no satisfiable in matrices but are satisfied in $\ell^1(G)$. On the other side, in a suitable form there is no such example known where one would be able to show that relations cannot be "almost" satisfied in matrices (given a suitable norm like the operator norm).

Comment: Can this be put in equational form: $xy = 1 \neq yx$? No matrix algebra has such  elements, but there are plenty of Banach algebras that do. More generally, there are traces on any subalgebra of a product of matrix algebras, but not for Banach algebras in general.

Comment: @RichardStanley  Dear Professor Stanley thank you very much for this interesting example.

Comment: @DavidHandelman  Dear Prof. Handelman,  according to your comment it would be interesting to find an equation which does not have a solution in finite dimensional $C^*$ algebras but it has a solution in a $C^*$ algebra which admit a faithful trace.Is there an equation with this property?

Comment: @DavidHandelman: You can express stronger conditions like the Cuntz algebra relations: $xy+wz=1$ and $yx=zw=1$.

Comment: @AndreasThom  In fact in the Cuntz algebra there is nontrivial projection which is a commutator. But this can not be happen in finite  dimensional case. But I wonder whether every nontrivial projection in the Cuntz algebra (of order 2 or higher order) is a commutator?